# How to do numpy multidimensional indexing with 2D indexing array of variable internal sizes

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, size

I am trying to create a smoothing algorithm in Blender for UVs with NumPy. I have 2 NumPy arrays. One is of shape [n,2] called "uv_list" where 'n' is the number of vertices selected. The other's shape is [n,x]  called "connected_ind" where x is the number of other vertices connected to the vertex of the index with each x being a NumPy array of variable size.

Example of arrays (as printed out from my program):

```
uv_list = [[0.         0.        ]
[0.57460427 0.4089092 ]
[0.48790365 0.45793641]
...
[0.55694079 0.39607367]
[0.56155378 0.40128589]
[0.56588227 0.40614387]]

connected_ind: [array([ 28, 103, 147,  29,  74]) array([ 44, 224,  43,  73, 193])
 array([ 14, 104, 254,  58, 223]) ...
 array([2605, 2607, 2592, 2593,   40,   41])
 array([2606, 2608, 2593, 2594,   41,   42])
 array([  43,   44, 2607, 2594,   45,   42])]
```

How would I then get another numpy array  of shape [n,x,2] filled with uvs? Or put another way how can I index uv_list in such a way that I get arrays of uvs that I can then np.average or np.mean?

Example of array to average (as I assume it would/should look):

```
indexed_uvs = [
array([0.1234, 0.5678],[0.5879,0.3564],[0.2548,0.7512]),
array([0.9124, 0.1248],[0.8654,0.1245],[0.7415,0.3698],[0.2548,0.5814]),
...
array([0.6578, 0.1245]),
array([0.3784, 0.6575],[0.8456,0.2134])
]
```

Which I would then want to average each line and have an array of shape [n,2] to assign back to the vertices:

```
np.average(indexed_uvs, axis=1)
```

What I've tried so far is "uvs[ind]" but that returns an error of:

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

I assume it's because each array of connected_ind is stored as a ndarray due to each array being different sizes but not sure how to fix this. I tried using a plain python list of lists for connected_ind but I get roughly the same error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Code that should simulate my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import random

i = 10
n = 20

# Simulate my array of uvs ( list of floats, shape = [n,2] )
uv_list = np.random.random_sample([n,2])

# Simulate my array of indices ( list of variable sized lists of ints, shape = [n,x] )
x = np.random.randint(1,high=7,size=n)
connected_ind = np.array( [ np.array( [np.random.randint(0,high=n) for _ in range(num)] ) for num in x] )

# Simulate an array of indices with same sized lists at dimension 1
#connected_ind = np.random.randint(0,high=n,size=[n,4])

for _ in range(i):
    print(_)
    # Get list of uvs by list of indices
    indexed_uvs = uv_list[connected_ind] # ERRORS HERE

    # Average each row of uv coordinates
    uv_list = np.average(indexed_uvs, axis=1)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `connected_ind` is a list of arrays of different sizes.  It's not (n,x), since `x` is not consistent.  `[uvlist[row,:] for row in connect_ind]` will give a list of 2d arrays, with variable 1st dimension.  Or `[np.averate(uvlist[row,:], 1) for ....]` if you just want the average (you may want axis 0).

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj! Yeah `(n,x)` was more theoretical indexing than real. That's why I explained what x was after. Okay so I've replaced `indexed_uvs = uv_list[connected_ind]` and `uv_list = np.average(indexed_uvs, axis=1)`  (everything inside the for loop) with `uv_list = [np.average(uv_list[row,:], axis=1) for row in connected_ind]` it gives me this error: _TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple_
Do you know why?

Comment: `uv_list` must not be an array, and `connected_ind` not a 2d array.  Review basic Python list indexing if necessary.

Comment: @hpaulj surrounding the list comprehension with a `np.array()` fixed it. It's still pretty realitively slow when upping the `n` to something more realistic like 2000 or higher. Any idea why that might be?